# Convert checklist auto submit code to checklist with submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the checklist radio button code I am using right now, I would like to convert it into a checklist with submit button. Currently, selecting one option will filter the result instantly, but i want to select multiple options and click submit button to get result. I want to use it without effecting the existing functions, as an addon feature.
In short it should allow to select more than one option at a time and submit.
Someone give me an example on how to do this ?
I am trying to learn JQuery and javascript, and need someone's help.
I tried but couldn't get a working result.

I want to use this method

```
<form>
<ul>
  Brand
<li><input name="Samsung" type="checkbox" value="Samsung" /> Samsung</li>
<li><input name="OnePlus" type="checkbox" value="OnePlus" /> OnePlus</li>
<li><input name="Apple" type="checkbox" value="Apple" /> Apple</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  RAM
<li><input name="1GB" type="checkbox" value="1GB" /> 1GB</li>
<li><input name="2GB" type="checkbox" value="2GB" /> 2GB</li>
</ul>
<div><button id="apply">Apply</button> <button id="apply">Clear</button></div>
</form>
```

So that the filter will not apply automatically, this funtion is for mobile pages.
and in PC, the regular auto filter will work.

Example image attached
[image: checklist with apply/submit button]

```
<h3>Sort</h3>
<div class="list-group-item checkbox">
<label for="radio1">
<input type="radio" id="radio" class="common_selector brand" name="radio" value="Samsung"> Samsung
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" class="common_selector brand" name="radio" value="Apple" > Apple
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" class="common_selector brand" name="radio" value="Nokia" > Nokia
</label>
<label>
</div>
```

The following JQuery function is capturing data from this checklist

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
        var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
        var brand = get_filter('brand');
        var sort = get_filter('sort');
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, minimum_price:minimum_price, maximum_price:maximum_price, brand:brand, sort:sort},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });
        return filter;
    }

    $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

    $('#price_range').slider({
        range:true,
        min:1000,
        max:95000,
        values:[1000, 95000],
        step:500,
        stop:function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
            $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
            filter_data();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

I tried the following code, but it didn't work.

```
   <form>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Samsung"> Samsung
        <input type="checkbox" value="Apple"> Apple

        <input type="button"  id="apply" class="common_selector brand" value="Submit">
    </form>
 

    $('#apply').click(function(){
  filter_data();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the html,  convert the radiobuttons to checkboxes. Then create the Apply button.   In the script,  connect the click event of the Apply button to the filter_data function.

```
   <form>
        <input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="samsung" value="Samsung"> Samsung
        <input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="apple" value="Apple"> Apple

        <button id="apply" class="common_selector brand">Apply</button>
    </form>
```

The script would then be

```
$('#apply').click(function(){
  filter_data();
});
```

In place of "$('#apply')" you will include a selector for the button, which can be based on the identifier (as above).

Comment: :-) Can you help me with the "connect the click event of the Apply button to the filter_data function" ?

Comment: thank you for spending your time. I tried this and didn't work for me. ` <form> <input type="checkbox" value="Samsung"> Samsung <input type="checkbox" value="Apple"> Apple <input type="button" id="apply" class="common_selector brand" value="Submit"> </form>. I have little knowledge about JQuery.

Comment: A button is a html element. Edited to show the difference.

Comment: thanks to your help, I fixed it in a different way without using the button. I will update the question with the solution. thanks again.